# function to perform swapping in an array

Tags: mips, swap, cpu-architecture, qtspim

The basic flow of the program is as follows: 
1.  Print the original content of array. 
2.  Ask the user for two indices X and Y. 
3.  Swap the two elements if Array[X] > Array[Y]. 
4.  Print the modified array only if swapping occurs.

```
.data  
array: .word 8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 7, 3, 5, 0, 4 
newl: .asciiz "\n" 
      .text 
la $a0, array
li $a1, 10
jal printArray
 #Ask the user for two indices 
 li   $v0, 5           #System call code for read_int
 syscall            
 addi $t0, $v0, 0      # first user input in $t0 
 li   $v0, 5           #System call code for read_int 
 syscall            
 addi $t1, $v0, 0      # second user input in $t1 

swap   :   li $a1, 0            #inx1
           li $a2, 0            #inx2
           sll $t0, $a1, 2      # $t0 = inx1* 4
           add $t0, $t0, $a0    # $t0 is the address of  A[$a1]
           sll $t3, $a2, 2      # $t3 = inx2* 4
           add $t3, $t3, $a0    # $t3 is the address of A[$a2]
           lw $t1, 0($t0)       # $t1 = A[$a1]
           lw $t2, 0($t3)       # $t2 = A[$a2]
           ble $t1, $t2, noPrint# if A[$a1] <=A[$a2] goto noPrint
           sw $t1, 0($t3)       # do the swap   
           sw $t2, 0($t0)       # do the swap
           syscall
           jal printArray

printArray: 
  addi $t1, $a0, 0        #$t1 is the pointer to the item 
  sll  $t2, $a1, 2        #$t2 is the offset beyond the last item 
  add  $t2, $a0, $t2      #$t2 is pointing beyond the last item 
loop: beq  $t1, $t2, end 
         lw   $t3, 0($t1)          #$t3 is the current item 
         li   $v0, 1               # system call code for print_int 
         addi $a0, $t3, 0          # integer to print 
         syscall                   # print it 
         addi $t1, $t1, 4 
         j loop                    # Another iteration 
end: 
  li   $v0, 4                 # system call code for print_string 
  la   $a0, newl              #  
  syscall                     # print newline 
   jr $ra                     # return from this function 
noPrint: 
  li   $v0, 10                # system call code for exit 
  syscall                     # terminate program
```

I'm having problems with swap function. It doesn't print anything on console window(using QtSpim). Can you please recommend any suggestion?

Comment: Start by writing the code in a higher level language and only then translate it to assembly. I recommend C, since it is easy to compile for humans.